# How to Create video from Mapbox camera animation

Tags: android, video, mapbox, record, mapbox-android

Below is my code of mapbox camera animation.How i create a 5 or 10 second video  from this. Iam using below mapbox library

```
 implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.12.1'

 mapboxMap.cameraAnimationsPlugin {
             animateCameraAlongPolyline(mapboxMap,curvedLine,animationDuration)  }

 fun animateCameraAlongPolyline(mapboxMap: MapboxMap, polyline: LineString, animationDuration: Long) {

    val coordinates = polyline.coordinates()
    val timeDelay = animationDuration / coordinates.size
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        for (i in 0 until coordinates.size - 1) {
            val start = coordinates[i]
            val end = coordinates[i +1]

            val cameraOptions = CameraOptions.Builder()
                .center(calculateMidpoint(start,end))
                .pitch(20.0)
                .build()
            // Instantly move the camera to the current point
            mapboxMap.setCamera(cameraOptions)
            delay(timeDelay)

        }
    }
}
```